# Passing props from outlet to parent using React Router 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using React Router V6 and im trying to figure out if I can pass props from nested routes which  are rendered using `Outlet` components. I can't seem to figure it out though. Can anyone help?

E.g. trying to pass the title prop from `BleTable` ("Bluetooth") to `App`

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App title="**Title from outlet**" />} >
          <Route path="ble" element={<BleTable title="Bluetooth"/>}/>
          <Route path="create-user" element={<UserForm/>}/>
        </Route>
      </Routes>

    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't pass props, per se, but you can provide a context value to the `Outlet` that `App` is rendering that the routed components can access via the  [`useOutletContext` hook](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useoutletcontext).

Example:

```
const AppLayout = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <h1>App: {title}</h1>
      <Outlet context={{ setTitle }} /> // <-- provide context value
    </>
  )
};

const BleTable = ({ title }) => {
  const { setTitle } = useOutletContext(); // <-- access context value

  return (
    <>
      <h1>BleTable</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setTitle(title)}>Update App Title</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

...

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<AppLayout />}>
      <Route path="ble" element={<BleTable title="Bluetooth" />} />
      <Route path="create-user" element={<UserForm/>}/>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

[image: Edit passing-props-from-outlet-to-parent-using-react-router-6]

Comment: how about passing children prop?

Comment: @JonathanJeshuaLaniba What about a `children` prop? Which component?

Comment: what i was trying to achieve is this:

```typescript
MyLayout.tsx // Layout Component
HomePage.tsx // Outlet Component
```

in HomePage.tsx, i want to pass ReactNode prop to MyLayout and display it.

Comment: @JonathanJeshuaLaniba You want a layout route component that renders some wrapped children components in addition to rendering an `Outlet` for the nested routes?

Comment: how to use `useOutletContext` inside react.Component class ?

Comment: @DimasLanjaka You can create a Higher Order Component that can use the `useOutletContext` hook and pass down the context value as a prop. The alternative is to convert the React Class component to a modern Function component and use the hook directly.